# Python script problems

Tags: python

So this is a script that I am coding for my buddies companies customer support. Basically, what it does is call using the IP phones that are in the script, it works, but with problems. Here is the code:

```
import urllib, urllib2, sys
num = sys.argv[1]
print 'Calling'
phones = [
'http://phone1/index.htm',
'http://phone2/index.htm',
'https://phone3/index.htm',
'https://phone4/index.htm',
'https://phone5/index.htm'
]
data = urllib.urlencode({"NUMBER":num, "DIAL":"Dial", "active_line":1})
while 1: 
    for phone in phones:
        try:
            urllib2.urlopen(phone,data) # make call
            urllib2.urlopen(phone+"?dialeddel=0") # clear logs
        except: pass
```

The first problem is that it only calls using phone one... Right now it is setup to keep calling over and over, for debugging purposes, and I seem to only be getting calls from phone one... The second problem is that the script will not terminate. ctrl+c does not work... The only way to terminate it (that I know of) is to end the ssh session. Now, I am new to python so both of these are probably just stupid mistakes so hopefully someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Step one is to take out that `except: pass` and see if it's generating any errors.

Comment: Try to use `ctrl + z` to terminate. If it does nothig, you can open another ssh session and perfom `killall python`

Comment: "The second problem is that the script will not terminate. ctrl+c does not work..."  You explicitly told it not to let you control-C it.  `KeyboardInterrupt` -- such as is raised by hitting ctrl-c -- is an exception too, and `except: pass` says that if any exception occurs, ignore it.  If you hold down control-C for long enough, you'll luck out and break it eventually.

Comment: Here is the error it gets,   File "p.py", line 16
    
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @DSM I didn't know that terminating the script was an exception.

Comment: I have the ctrl+c problem fixed, the only calling with one number is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the try catch block like this,

```
try:
    <code>
except Exception as exp:
    <code>
```

While using the below code.

```
except:
    pass
```

The system will catch SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt and other things that you probably don't want to catch.

Thanks.

Comment: That seems to yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your try block may be catching the Ctrl-C. Try modifying it so you only catch the specific exceptions you expect. See [KeyboardInterrupt](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) for more about Ctrl-C as an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
try:
    urllib2.urlopen(phone,data) # make call
    urllib2.urlopen(phone+"?dialeddel=0") # clear logs
except: pass
```

with:

```
urllib2.urlopen(phone,data) # make call
urllib2.urlopen(phone+"?dialeddel=0") # clear logs
```

so you can see traceback and find the error

Comment: When doing that, it will call just once and output Calling... but then it shows this... http://pastebin.com/vnHyHFnR